# jquery intercepting paste event

Tags: jquery

I've binded a paste event from an input:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.myInput').bind("paste",function(e) {
          console.log(e);
      });
});​
```

Everytime I hit CTRL-V it returns the `e` event object.

I want to get the data the user is about to paste in the input.

By inspecting the event object I found the value in several places such as:

- `e.srcElement.value`
- `e.target.value`

But those ones return the value in the input after the paste happened. So If I paste some text after I entered another string, I'll get both strings concatenated.

I've search trought the internet and found nothing but ugly flash solutions.

Is there a clean way to do this in jquery?

I thought about getting the whole text with `e.srcElement.value` after getting the input value `before` the paste, then compare both string and eliminate the first part, returning by consecuence the value of the clipboard.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to clear the input before the copied text is inserted?

Comment: @StevenFarley I want to get the string that the user just pasted to the input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this is what your trying to do, not 100% sure:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" class="myInput" value="This is some default text" />​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').on('paste', function (e) { //Attach paste event handler for all inputs
        $(this).val('').val(e.target.value); //Clear the current value, then insert the value of the data that was pasted
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PMq6U/

Comment: Almost :) I still need to get the pasted value as a variable inside the event. I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/jviotti/PMq6U/3/ alert should be returning the new value. Instead it returns nothing, as if it was invoked before the val().

Comment: @RicardoLohmann It set's the value to blank, and then sets it to pasted value.

Comment: @jviotti: You can use the old `setTimeout` with `1ms` hack. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/PMq6U/4/

Comment: Seems to work fine, I'll implemented and accept the answer. Just for extra... any chances to make this work with the middle-mouse-wheel-click unix paste? :)

Answer (score 2):

clipboardData works for modern browsers (IE11+, Firefox, Chrome...).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.myInput').on('paste', function (e) {
          var dt = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
          if(dt && dt.items && dt.items[0]){
              dt.items[0].getAsString(function(text){
                  console.log(text); //the pasted content
              });
          }else if(dt && 'getData' in dt){
              console.log(dt.getData('text')); //the pasted content
          }
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6n10y0ds/9/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer

Answer (score -1):

You can use the onbeforepaste event to do it.

```
$(function(){
    $('#el').on('beforepaste',function(e){
        [...]
    });
});
```

Comment: documentation? I can't find that event anywhere. Is it browser specific?

Comment: Originally it's only for IE but now it's in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Still Im not sure how much cross-browser solution is this.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work on your browser. It works fine on mine. See [this](http://serve-licson.net23.net/images/img01.PNG).